# How to call API written in C# through Angular (ionic 4)

Tags: c#, angularjs, api, ionic-framework, ionic4

I have created a login page using angular and ionic. Now I have my API written in C# which I want to call when the user click on login button.

```
[Route("api/LoginforApp/"), HttpPost]
        public string LoginforApp([FromBody] LoginModel user)
        {
            char quote = '"';
            try
            {
                if (defaulttoken == user.Token)
                {
                    int flag = PassEncryptornot(user.Email);
                    if (flag == 0)
                    {
                        password = user.Password == null ? "" : user.Password;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        string pswd = Encrypt(user.Password == null ? "" : user.Password);
                        password = pswd;
                    }
                    db.AddParameter("@Emailid", user.Email == null ? "" : user.Email);
                    db.AddParameter("@password", password);
                    ds = db.ExecuteDataSet("ps_MemberLogin", CommandType.StoredProcedure);
                    dt = ds.Tables[0];
                    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                    {
                        //var response = dt.Rows[0]["Message"].ToString();
                        var result = dt;
                        var json = DataTableToJSONWithJSONNet(dt);
                        return json;

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return "Invalid Username and Password.";
```

how can I call this code in my ionic - angular app ?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer will be :

It doesn't matter what the BE is written in as an API is just an API, as long as your backend knows how to handle requests it doesn't matter, that's the beauty of be/fe seperation.

To actually create a request you can use the `HttpClient` module.

do something like `this.httpClient.get<T>('${c#serverURL}/${api}')`.

read more at https://angular.io/guide/http